# Saving an Image in App Directory instead of going to photo album. Objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, camera

Hello I have an app that takes pictures but doesn't save. I know how to save the image to the Photo Album but I need the image to go to the app's directory and will not show up in the Photos gallery. I already have searched and I failed to look for a working one. I also need that image to be in my `UIImageView` when I open my app. Here are my codes:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
    UIImagePickerController *picker2;
    UIImage *image;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

-(IBAction)TakePhoto;
-(IBAction)ChooseExisting;
- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnLoad:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)TakePhoto{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
   // [picker release];


}

- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MyImage.png"] ];
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}
-(IBAction)ChooseExisting{
    picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker2.delegate=self;
    [picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
    // [picker release];

}

- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {

    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MyImage.png"]];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
         NSLog(@"saved");
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnLoad:(id)sender {
    [self loadImage];
}



-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self loadImage];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The Save and loadImage methods don't work :(. No idea why but I don't have any errors.

Comment: Check whether your image is stored in the documents directory.

Comment: Have you checked that `btnSave` is called if you touch the button? Have you checked the values of `image`, `path`, `data` in the debugger? Have you checked the return value of `writeToFile:atomically:`?

Comment: btnSave is called, checking to see if the image is stored in the documents directory later. Don't have the iPhone to use it on yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image saving/loading code seems correct.

Check if your `IBActions` are properly connected in IB.

And change:

```
- (IBAction)btnLoad:(id)sender
{
    [self loadImage];
}
```

to:

```
- (IBAction)btnLoad:(id)sender
{
    [self loadImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
}
```

Your original code seems to load the image but it doesn't show it anywhere.

EDIT:

You can always check if the image is saved to documents directory.
With the device connected open the organizer window in XCode.

Select your device, then select applications. Choose the application
you're interested in and you should see the file-tree related to that
app. Is your image file listed in the Documents folder?

Comment: that solved my problem the easiest way :)..THANKS ALOT! also ty too all the other answers too :)

Answer (score 1):

Check in documents directory for image. Your calling [self loadImage]; but loadImage return UIImage which your not using anywhere. You can attach data to picker like the following.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImage.png"];
NSData *myData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appFile] autorelease];
[picker2 addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"MyImage"];
```